# No wget domain resolution in crontab

Tags: networking, cron, wget

I need to download a file when my computer boots up, so I created this line in my cronjob:

```
@reboot wget -a /log/here -O /save/here https://domain.tld/file.ext
```

Unfortunately, it creates a blank file at `/save/here` and gives me an error at `/log/here`.

The error says:

```
Resolving domain.tld (domain.tld)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ■domain.tld■
```

Is this because name resolution isn't available so early in the boot process? Besides replacing the domain with an ip address bypassing name resolution, is there anything else I can do? I'd like to keep this all within the crontab.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [systemd](/questions/tagged/systemd) unit file with dependency of `network`, or you can try this :

```
@reboot until ping -c1 dk &>/dev/null; do sleep 2; done; wget -a /log/here -O /save/here https://domain.tld/file.ext
```

(`dk` is the shortest domain name I know)

Comment: Thank you. I tried the above and it still didn't resolve. Then I setup my domain with an ip address and it still didn't work (it worked in the browser on another computer but my wget log it said: failed: Network is unreachable). Now I'm trying to figure out the systemd unit file with dependency of network, but having a hard time finding examples.

Comment: 1) what is your distro ? 2) is `ping dk` works in terminal ?

Comment: Would need to ping an ip address like 8.8.8.8 so it does not fail early on name resolution

Comment: just keep on trying wget. `@reboot until  wget -a /log/here -O /save/here https://domain.tld/file.ext; do sleep 2; done`

Comment: @GillesQuenot its Raspbian

Answer (score 0):

I found that the most reliable way to use wget at bootup was to create a job in `/etc/rc.local`. Also, as the computer I was using doesn't have an internal battery and instead relies on Network Time Protocol to set its clock on boot up, I found that I had to also specify the `--no-check-certificate` or not use https:// to prevent the command from failing due issues such as the SSL certificate not being valid yet.